# TcpListener: "All Unassigned IP" address like feature

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcplistener

Trying to understand what would be a better approach or better solutions, considering the target machines where the program will be deployed could have teamed network cards or just failover cards

I have a windows service that hosts a service over a port XXXX. It is not a WCF service but a simple TcpListner and socket bind to a port kind of a service. Currently, it is written to bind to an IP address at service start, which is clunky. I am looking for a way to make the service host IIS like "All Unassigned IP" feature that seems to work well with both teaming and NIC failover modes.

Options I have in mind are,

1. Use **IPAddress.Any** ... I don't have experience using this mode both with NIC teaming and failover
2. Or iterate through each NIC using **System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()** results and bind to the **GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses**

Recommendation or if there are other suggestions

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `IPAddress.Any` it appears to be what you are looking for. "The Socket.Bind method uses the Any field to indicate that a Socket instance must listen for client activity on all network interfaces."

Answer (score 3):

Bind to 0.0.0.0. That means "all local addresses".

Comment: `IPAddress.Any` is identical to this.

Comment: Thanks Seva & Guvante. I realize I can use either but I need to understand whether this approach would work support NIC teaming and failover?

Comment: Not yet, this is the next thing to do ... post my feedback soon

Comment: Seva, EJP & Guvante, We tried the 0.0.0.0 with 2 networks cards configured in failover mode. The service is unable to bind to an IP. We are investigating the server configuration but doesn't look promising

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. :)